# Status strip and Time

Tags: c#

Im creating a game ... I want to add a counter as a clock exactly the same as the Time counter in Microsoft solitair game & i want later when the game is over the time stop and the time reached to be saved in a variable what ever but i want to use this number to generate a scores table.

thanx in advance....
I will post the whole game when its 100% done so you guys can Enjoy :-)

Comment: What's exactly your question?

Comment: how to create this time & let it stop when the game is over & save the time reached

Comment: Please don't post the whole game here. Do not use StackOverflow as your personal blog.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a Stopwatch object.

Here's a link on how to use it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx

To start the stopwatch do this:

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();
```

To stop:

```
stopWatch.Stop();
        // Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed; // gets elapsed time
```

To show time that's elapsed:

```
// Format and display the TimeSpan value.
        string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
            ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
            ts.Milliseconds / 10);
```

Now you can display the 'elapsedtime' string in your strip.

EDIT:

To see moving time, put following in Button click handler to start time:

```
    // global variable
        string timeelepse = string.empty; 
   // in button click handler
    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();


            sw.Start();

            System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(delegate()
            {
                while (true)
                {
                TimeSpan ts = sw.Elapsed;

                string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
                ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
                ts.Milliseconds / 10);

                timeelepse = elapsedTime;

                  UpdateLabel();
                }
            });
            t.Start();
```

Now add these two functions & delegate to your forms class:

```
public delegate void doupdate();
        public void UpdateLabel()
        {
            doupdate db = new doupdate(DoUpdateLabel);
            this.Invoke(db);
        }

        public void DoUpdateLabel()
        {
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = timeelepse;
        }
```

Comment: Im kinda lost in that code on MSDN ... :-( I need help I dont think I need all these things

Comment: What about the timer in the toolbox cant I use this ? if so how ?

Comment: If you need to do something every interval then you should use a timer, for just counting time, I think a stopwatch fits better.  I edited my answer for you.

Comment: I did this before you paste it here and finally I add statusStrip1.Text = elapsedTime; but nothing is displaying on the statusstrip !!!

Comment: which event I should modify in the status strip ?

Comment: You should add a ToolstripStatuslabel to your form and set its text property to the elapsedtime string.

Comment: yes tony but its not moving I ment The time will change only if i clicked on the toolstriplabel its not moving by it self

Comment: @ Tony Thanx for your help I got it , I had to a Timer and assign the string to it

Comment: You're welcome.  I updated anyway with code to see time elapsing using stopwatch. :)